# Lazy Load OneToMany

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, lazy-loading

Ola.

Estou com dificuldades em fazer funcionar os meus relacionamentos fetch = FetchType.LAZY com a anotação @OneToMany.
Na minha entidade NotaFiscal, há várias listas fetch = FetchType.LAZY, ao fazer o load do objeto pelo id, carrego todas estas listas com left outer join. Em primeira instância (depurando) todas as listas são carregadas. Porem, no momento em que eu troco de aba e é feita a requisição da lista de emails (listaEmail) está me retornando o erro:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: br.inf.criare.erp.nota.domain.NotaFiscal.listaEmail, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Para tentar explicar melhor, segue parte da classe NotaFiscal

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notas_fiscais")
public class NotaFiscal implements IEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "notaFiscal", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
        orphanRemoval = true)
private List<NotaFiscalItem> itens;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "notaFiscal", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
        orphanRemoval = true)
private List<NotaFiscalDocRef> listaDocRef;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "notaFiscal", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
        orphanRemoval = true)
private List<NotaFiscalProcRef> listaProcRef;

//-----------------------------------------------------
//GRUPO DE CAMPO DE USO LIVRE
//----------------------------------------------------- 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "notaFiscal", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL},
        orphanRemoval = true)
private List<NotaFiscalObsCont> listaObsCont;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "notaFiscal", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        orphanRemoval = true,
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<NotaFiscalVeiculo> veiculos;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "notaFiscal", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        orphanRemoval = true,
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<NotaFiscalVolumes> volumes;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "notaFiscal", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
        orphanRemoval = true)
private List<NotaFiscalEvento> eventos;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "notas_fiscais_email", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="nota_fiscal_id"))
private List<NotaFiscalEmail> listaEmail;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "documento", length = 20, nullable = false)
@CollectionTable(name = "notas_fiscais_autxml", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="nota_fiscal_id"))
private List<String> listaAutXml;
```

Método que faz o load pelo id:

```
private NotaFiscal loadLazy(Long id) {
    try {
        String sql = "select o from NotaFiscal as o "
                + "left outer join o.listaEmail le "
                + "left outer join o.listaAutXml la "
                + "left outer join o.pagamentos p "
                + "left outer join o.duplicatas du "
                + "left outer join o.itens i "
                + "left outer join o.listaDocRef ldr "
                + "left outer join o.listaProcRef lpr "
                + "left outer join o.listaObsCont obs "
                + "left outer join o.eventos eve "
                + "left outer join o.volumes volumes "
                + "left outer join o.veiculos vei "
                + "where o.id = :id ";
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter("id", id);

        return (NotaFiscal) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        CriareLog.log(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Método em que acontece o erro no momento da requisição da lista.

```
public DataModel<NotaFiscalEmail> getEmailsDM() {
    if (emailsDM == null) {
        if (this.getBean().getListaEmail() == null) {
            this.getBean().setListaEmail(new ArrayList<NotaFiscalEmail>());
        }
        // O erro ocorre exatamente nesta linha.
        emailsDM = new ListDataModel<NotaFiscalEmail>(this.getBean().getListaEmail()); 
    }
    return emailsDM;
}
```

Se precisar de mais alguma coisa vai falando que eu vou postando aqui.
Agradeço a ajuda de todos.
Abraços

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro `LazyInitializationException` é um dos mais comuns e mal entendidos por quem usa Hibernate.

## Como o `LazyInitializationException` ocorre

O importante para entender o erro é que o Hibernate posterga o carregamento dos relacionamentos do tipo *lazy* para quando o método *getter* do relacionamento for chamado, isto é, ele não carrega todos os dados quando os métodos `getSingleResult` ou `getResultList` são chamados.

O problema é que a sessão (e a conexão com o banco) ainda precisa estar aberta no momento em que o *getter* é chamado, o que nem sempre é verdade nas camadas mais "altas" da aplicação, tais como nos *controllers* e *views*.

Portanto, o erro `LazyInitializationException` ocorre enquanto seu *controller* ou sua  *view* chama um determinado método `get` e o Hibernate, que intercepta essa chamada através de um *proxy*, não consegue mais fazer a chamada necessário ao banco de dados.

## Solução #1: trazer tudo do banco de dados e uma vez

Trazer tudo do banco de dados é uma alternativa para evitar o erro. Porém, os comandos `left outer join` não servem para isso.

O correto seria usar um ***Fetch Join***. Ver documentação [*Improving performance*](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html).

## Solução #2: não fechar a sessão

Outra solução comumente usada é manter a sessão aberta. Este é o método mais fácil, porém, muitos [consideram](http://java.dzone.com/articles/opensessioninview-antipattern) como um [anti-padrão](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1103363/1683070).

É difícil não concordar que parece uma má ideia objetos consultando o banco enquanto se escreve a *view* em HTML para o usuário.

## Solução #3: force as consultas manualmente

**Esta é mais uma gambiarra, mas fica aqui para registro.**

Uma alternativa para forçar o carregamento dos relacionamentos é invocar dentro da sua camada de banco de dados os métodos que recuperam as entidades relacionadas, mesmo que não faça com elas.

Seria o equivalente ao que ocorre durante o *debug*, só que com chamadas de métodos de verdade no código.

## Solução #4: use DTOs

Recuperar todos os dados necessários nas camadas que acessam o banco de dados e retornar objetos "enxutos" somente com os dados necessários também é uma abordagem válido.

Algumas pessoas não gostam disso, mas considero uma alternativa melhor do que expor o modelo e o acesso a banco de dados para as camadas *view* e *controller*.

## Porque depurando funciona?

Porque quando o *breakpoint* está parado dentro do método a sessão está aberta e o Hibernate consegue carregar as entidades relacionadas.

Muita gente não se apercebe disso, mas inspecionar um trecho qualquer de código na verdade executa aquele trecho. Se um método inspecionado afeta o estado de alguns objetos, o estado fará parte do programa que está executando.

Já ouviu falar sobre [Heisenberg](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_incerteza_de_Heisenberg)?

## Conclusão

Procure usar *fetch joins*.

Se não puder, sugiro armazenar a consulta em DTOs.

Comment: Boa tarde. Ótima explicação, quando estou com algum problema sempre procuro pesquisar de onde as coisas vem e para que realmente elas funcionam para melhor entende-las. Portanto, acabei verificando que eu deveria usar o join fetch, no entanto, apos atualizar a pesquisa de load para join fetch estou com o seguinte problema: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags. Já estou a procura da solução, mas também estou com dificuldades! Agradeço muito a sua ajuda!

Comment: @GilvanAndré O problema é que não é possível fazer fetch de várias listas ao mesmo tempo, porque isso é inviável via SQL. Acho que terá que usar outra alternativa.

Comment: Cara, que dor de cabeça isso! Eu não gostaria de utilizar OpenSessionInView. Meu maior problema é que eu precisaria otimizar as pesquisas/relatórios, que devido a utilização do EAGER é lento de mais. Passando a utilizar Lazy, a pesquisa funciona perfeitamente, porem acabo sofrendo com outros problemas! De qualquer forma muito obrigado pela resposta, sensacional! Meus parabéns!

Comment: @GilvanAndré Outra coisa que você pode fazer é montar na mão cada objeto ou lista necessária ao invés de compor um "objeto monstro" de uma só vez. Eu entendo bem sua dor de cabeça, e é por isso que tenho evitado JPA ao máximo. Simplesmente chega uma hora que as facilidades não compensam os problemas que ele trás.

Comment: Pois é, nossa aplicação está se tornando grande. E a algum tempo já estamos pensando em "abandonar" JPA. Mesmo tentando utilizá-lo da melhor forma, as vezes ele da mais trabalho do que não utilizá-lo!

Comment: @GilvanAndré Pois é. Outra coisa que você pode tentar fazer nesses casos é usar *native queries* quando necessário. Porém mesmo assim não vai conseguir trazer todos aqueles dados de uma vez só.

Comment: @GilvanAndré O problema é usar JPA do jeito errado e não o JPA em si. Escreva queries para relatórios em vez de usar a API da entidade para resgatar coleções através da entidade raiz. Não precisa ser native query, pode ser HQL e você continua tendo a capacidade de usar termos de negócio em vez de nomes de campos e tabelas. Apenas escreva as queries que precisa, quantas precisar, em vez de esperar carregamento automático de objetos filhos. Entregue o resultado destas queries em estruturas de dados relevantes ao relatório em vez de em coleções de objetos de negócio.

Comment: @Caffé Para relatórios eu utilizo esta estrutura que você colocou, a questão aqui não é para uso em relatórios, mas sim para utilizá-lo em um CRUD. Sendo que este CRUD é em JSF. Portado ao fechar a seção(por exemplo: submeter a pagina), eu não tenho mais acesso as variáveis que estão Lazy. A minha solução seria manter a sessão aberta, mas é a ultima solução que quero utilizar. Por hora estamos utilizando EAGER mesmo, mas os estudos continuam para tentar achar uma solução mais eficiente.

Comment: Outra opção que estamos estudando utilizar são os DTOs, como sitou o amigo ao responder a pergunta. Isso também não está fora de cogitação, e também poderá ser o caminho para resolver o problema.

Comment: @GilvanAndré Você escreveu relatórios no seu comentário. Sim, no meu comentário (estruturas de dados) eu estou concordando com a opção de DTOs do utluiz - serve para relatórios e também para manipulação na camada de apresentação.

Comment: @Caffé A sim... no comentário sim! :D