# Como usar Lazy Loading

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-jpa

Estou tentando fazer usar a anotação ManyToOne com lazy loading mas está dando erro. O código é bem simples e ele funciona quando eu uso fetch eager mas com o lazy ele não funciona e eu não sei porque.

Segue código da Entidade Project

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;
}
```

Log do erro:

```
2023-03-29 14:37:46.754  WARN 15144 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy [com.guilherme.crm.entities.Customer#1] - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy [com.guilherme.crm.entities.Customer#1] - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->com.guilherme.crm.entities.Project["customer"]->com.guilherme.crm.entities.Customer$HibernateProxy$w9fGIQnw["name"])]
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33443/lazy-load-onetomany?rq=1

Answer (score -2):

O lazy loading parece estar funcionando. O log sugere que, quando o sistema tentou empacotar a entidade *Project* em um JSON, a sessão já havia sido terminada. Portanto, o load da entidade *Customer*, que ainda não havia sido carregada justamente por causa da anotação `FetchType.Lazy`, falhou.

Então, o que fazer nessas situações?

### Opção 1: usar o FetchType.EAGER

Ou, para os relacionamentos `@ManyToOne`, não definir nenhum `fetchType` e usar o default que é `FetchType.EAGER`.

Nesse caso, a entidade relacionada será carregada no momento que a entidade dona da relação é carregada.

### Opção 2: garantir que a transação ainda esteja aberta

O código do componente que usa as entidades `Project` e `Customer` não foi mostrado. Mas, vamos supor que se trate de um controller que usa um repositório para buscar objetos da entidade `Project`. Nesse caso, basta garantir que, no momento que o objeto `Customer` for recuperado, a transação esteja aberta. Teríamos algo como:

```java
public ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Long> { }

@RestController("/projects")
public class ProjectController {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository repo;

    @GetMapping
    @Transactional // garante a existência de uma transação durante a chamada ao método
    public Collection<ProjectDTO> getAll() {
        return repo.findAll().map(p -> {
            return new ProjectDTO(
                p,
                p.getCustomer() // Para caso LAZY, esse é o gatilho para o JPA acessar a tabela customer
            );
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

### Opção 3: "forçar" a carga da entidade do relacionamento dentro de uma transação

Nesse caso, vamos supor que, em vez de um método genérico do repositório, seja utilizado um método específico, para o qual foi necessário escrever o código de recuperação da entidade.

```java
@Repository
ProjectCustomRepository {
    List<Project> findImplementado(Object parametro);
}

ProjectCustomRepositoryImpl implements ProjectCustomRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<Project> findImplementado(Object parametro) {
        var list = em.createQuery("select p from Project p where parametro = :parametro", Project.class)
            .setParameter("parametro", parametro)
            .getResultList();

        for (var project : list) {
            project.getCustomer(); // força o load da entidade
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Então o Fetch Lazy não é recomendado quando se usa Spring? Como contornar essa situação?

Comment: Depende muito da necessidade. O lazy loading é bastante prático, por ex, numa situação de `@OneToMany` que você não vai ler o conteúdo da collection e quer trabalhar apenas com os dados de uma entidade. Uma outra forma, é você garantir que a sessão ainda exista quando os dados estiverem sendo empacotados. Outra opção ainda, é você "forçar" o load da relação lazy quando a sessão ainda estiver aberta.

Comment: @GuilhermeBorges Editei a resposta com exemplos das alternativas que deixei em meu último comentário.